# DNS nslookup failing on DNS server

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008

I am on one of the domain controllers and getting this issue with nslookup shown below, Why does it fail? other controllers don't have that issue. I have verified DNS config but didn't find anything wrong.

```
 C:\>Nslookup google.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out

C:\>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [172.217.3.206] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.217.3.206: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.3.206: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.3.206: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.3.206: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 172.217.3.206:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 19ms, Average = 17ms
```

if I do same on a workstation, it works fine.

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup google.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.253.178.20

Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:400a:809::200e
          172.217.3.206





C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ABC-SRV06
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : ABC.local
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : ABC.local

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 70-E2-84-0A-BE-98
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cca9:15c0:c477:590b%14(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.253.178.20(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.253.178.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 242279044
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-19-86-72-70-E2-84-0A-BE-97
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                       10.253.175.24
                                       10.253.178.20
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{4EECAC43-97C8-416C-B3EE-5C4374713D84}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

[NIC settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqn8V.png)

[IPV6 settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihmDS.png)

Comment: Can you share output from ipconfig /all? 

Is 127.0.0.1 configured as primary and then secondary being another DC?

Comment: nslookup trying to resolve domain on IPv6 address. Your DNS-server lister on IPv6 interface?

Comment: @kps Added output of ipconfig /all

Comment: @alexander-t you are probably right, but I was told that IPV6 is important and not to turn it off, but my other servers have IPV6 disabled. should I just disable it on the server too?

Comment: you have to get rid of ::1 from your DNS client configuration (on your network card)

Comment: @olivierg I did remove the localhost in the NIC settings, (see post for pic)
is there a different place to do that. maybe reboot is required. Will reboot tonight

Comment: Can you add 127.0.0.1 as the first DNS server and then add in additional as necessary? EDIT - Looks like things have changed since I've last setup a DNS server, loopback should be including but not as the first entry...see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff807362(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @kps I have added back 127.0.0.1 as the DNS (removed it earlier) but it doesn't fix the issue with  nslookup, still getting DNS request timeout.

Comment: What server does nslookup default to? Also try doing this: (<br> 

nslookup <enter>  set server 127.0.0.1 <enter> google.com <enter>

Comment: Could you show IPv6 NIC configuration?

Comment: @AlexanderT added image in main message for IPV6 settings

Answer (score 2):

After discussion in comments, I see that you have DNS server in your IPv6 configuration. Looks like it not properly configured, so you could easily change DNS settings in IPv6 to `Obtain DNS server address automatically` from `Use the following DNS server addresses`. It should solve your issue.